# Error while installing sap netweaver_as_abap_750_sp02_ase_dev_edition. in linux mint 64 bit

Tags: linux, ide, abap, sap-basis

When installing sap netweaver (netweaver_as_abap_750_sp02_ase_dev_edition) in my linux mint 64 bit I got the following error :

> (An error occurred while processing option System Rename > Standard System > SAP System Rename( Last error reported by the step: Assertion failed: Unable to generate a new password for database login 'sa'. Refer to trace file sapinst_dev.log for further information.). You can now: Choose Retry to repeat the current step. Choose Log Files to get more information about the error. Stop the option and continue later. Log files are written to /tmp/sapinst_instdir/NW73/SBC/STANDARD.

I am sharing the log files below.

```
TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [iaxxclib.cpp:170] CLib::load()
Opened sylib722.so

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcgroup.cpp:764] bool CSyUserImpl::isExistingOnOS()
checking existence of account group="root" gid="0" succeeded with true.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syxxccache.cpp:419] CSyAccountCache::addToCache(const IaPtr<CSyAccountImpl> account)
inserted account (root, 0, GROUP) into the accountcache.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:1996] bool CSyUserImpl::isExistingOnOS()
checking existence of account user="root" uid="0" succeeded with true.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syxxccache.cpp:419] CSyAccountCache::addToCache(const IaPtr<CSyAccountImpl> account)
inserted account (root, 0, USER) into the accountcache.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [CSiManagerInterfaces.cpp:2750] CSiComponentSet::getExePath()
exe dir is /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [CSiManagerInterfaces.cpp:2224]
MessageLib initialized successfully.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcpath.cpp:443] id=syslib.filesystem.creatingFile CSyPath::createFile()
Creating file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel_test_21_Jul_2018_18_40_35.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcfile.cpp:216] id=syslib.filesystem.removedFile CSyFileImpl::removeEx(ISyFSErrorHandler * pErrorHandler)
Removed file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel_test_21_Jul_2018_18_40_35.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syxxclogbook.cpp:215] PSyLogBook::initSAPKernelTracing(int traceLevel, const CSyPath & filePath)
Initialized SAP kernel tracing to file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [CSiComponentSetManager.cpp:112] CSiComponentSetManager::readFrameworkJslib()
Reading framework jslib.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [CSiComponentSetManager.cpp:146] CSiComponentSetManager::readFrameworkJslib()
Reading framework jslib done.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcaccmg.cpp:273] bool CSyAccountMgtImpl::isExisting(ISyAccountMgt::eAccountType accountType, iastring sName)
Account sapinst already exists.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxcgroup.cpp:764] bool CSyUserImpl::isExistingOnOS()
checking existence of account group="sapinst" gid="1001" succeeded with true.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syxxccache.cpp:419] CSyAccountCache::addToCache(const IaPtr<CSyAccountImpl> account)
inserted account (sapinst, 1001, GROUP) into the accountcache.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.093 (root/sapinst) [syuxccuren.cpp:171] id=syslib.process.currentProcessEnv.groupSetSuccessfully CSyCurrentProcessEnvironmentImpl::setGroup(PSyGroupInt)
Real group ID set to 1001.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:612] PSyGroupImpl CSyUserImpl::getPrimaryGroup()const
account user="root" uid="0" exists with parameter gid="0"

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:612] PSyGroupImpl CSyUserImpl::getPrimaryGroup()const
account user="root" uid="0" exists with parameter gid="0"

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:770] PSyAccountIterator CSyUserImpl::getMembership() const
account user="root" uid="0" exists with parameter groups="root,sapinst"

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:2230] CSyUserImpl::setMembership(const PSyGroupImpl & pGroup)
User is already member of group sapinst. Nothing to do.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [iaxxclib.cpp:68] id=syslib.process.currentProcessEnv.cwdSuccessful CChangeCWD::CChangeCWD(const iastring & /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621)
Working directory changed to /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [iaxxclib.cpp:170] CLib::load()
Opened /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621/iakdblib722.so

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [iaxxclib.cpp:94] id=syslib.process.currentProcessEnv.cwdSuccessful CChangeCWD::~CChangeCWD()
Working directory changed to /tmp/swpm.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcpath.cpp:443] id=syslib.filesystem.creatingFile CSyPath::createFile()
Creating file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel_test_21_Jul_2018_18_40_36.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcfile.cpp:216] id=syslib.filesystem.removedFile CSyFileImpl::removeEx(ISyFSErrorHandler * pErrorHandler)
Removed file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel_test_21_Jul_2018_18_40_36.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syxxclogbook.cpp:215] PSyLogBook::initSAPKernelTracing(int traceLevel, const CSyPath & filePath)
Initialized SAP kernel tracing to file /tmp/dev_sap_kernel

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [CServiceHelpers.cpp:86]
exe dir is /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcpath.cpp:481] id=syslib.filesystem.creatingDirectory CSyPath::createDirectory()
Creating directory /tmp/sapinst_instdir.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.094 (root/sapinst) [syuxcpath.cpp:443] id=syslib.filesystem.creatingFile CSyPath::createFile()
Creating file /tmp/sapinst_instdir/x.

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcfile.cpp:216] id=syslib.filesystem.removedFile CSyFileImpl::removeEx(ISyFSErrorHandler * pErrorHandler)
Removed file /tmp/sapinst_instdir/x.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [CServiceSelectionBase.cpp:355]
retrieving account information for group sapinst...

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcaccmg.cpp:273] bool CSyAccountMgtImpl::isExisting(ISyAccountMgt::eAccountType accountType, iastring sName)
Account sapinst already exists.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcnode.cpp:102] CSyNodeImpl::getACL()
getting ACL of /tmp/sapinst_instdir succeeded.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxccache.cpp:419] CSyAccountCache::addToCache(const IaPtr<CSyAccountImpl> account)
inserted account (Everyone, -17, GROUP) into the accountcache.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcuser.cpp:699] iastring CSyUserImpl::getHomeDirectory() const
account user="root" uid="0" exists with parameter home="/root"

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [SDTGui.cpp:133]
Starting GUIServer using:
SAPinst port : 21212
GUI autostart : on
GUI mode : normal
command : /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621/jre/bin/java -Xmx512M -Dsap.env.var.javahome=SAPINST_JRE_HOME -cp "/tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621/JAR/instgui.jar" SDTServer "rootdir=/root/.sdtgui" config=jar:sdtserver.xml guiport=21212 -nolock -srvarg=/SAPinstService/host=127.0.0.1 -srvarg=/SAPinstService/port=pipe:5:8

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxctask.cpp:229] CChildApplicationImpl::doStart()
A child process has been started. Pid = 8375

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:136] CSyACLImpl::editRight()
Editing rights (rwx): (1001, GROUP, =rwx)

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:145] CSyACLImpl::setRight()
Setting rights of sapinst to rwx

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:136] CSyACLImpl::editRight()
Editing rights (rwx): (0, USER, =rwx)

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:145] CSyACLImpl::setRight()
Setting rights of root to rwx

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:136] CSyACLImpl::editRight()
Editing rights (rwxt): (-17, GROUP, =rwxt)

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syxxcnodac.cpp:145] CSyACLImpl::setRight()
Setting rights of Everyone to rwxt

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcnode.cpp:317] CSyNodeImpl::setNativeACL(const NativeSecurityDesc_t & sd, ISyErrorHandler * pErrorHandler) const
chmod(/tmp/sapinst_instdir, 01777) succeeded

INFO 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcnode.cpp:326] id=syslib.filesystem.aclSetSucceeded CSyNodeImpl::setNativeACL(const NativeSecurityDesc_t & sd, ISyErrorHandler * pErrorHandler) const
Authorizations set for /tmp/sapinst_instdir.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [syuxcnode.cpp:333] CSyNodeImpl::setNativeACL(const NativeSecurityDesc_t & sd, ISyErrorHandler * pErrorHandler) const
Resulting security descriptor: Mode: 041777, uid: 0, gid: 1001

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [CServiceSelectionBase.cpp:382]
retrieving account information done.

TRACE 2018-07-21 18:40:44.095 (root/sapinst) [sixxcreate.cpp:44] startInstallationViaStarter()
```

My SAPinst build information is as follows:

```
Version: 2016.06.0
Build: 1676582
Compile time: Jun 17 2016 - 16:03:12
Make type: optu
Codeline: 720-2_REL
Platform: linuxx86_64
Kernel build: 721, patch 626, changelist 1662147
SAP JRE build: SAP Java Server VM (build 6.1.087 25.51-b02, Mar 1 2016 10:01:52 - 61_REL - optU - linux amd64 - 6 - bas2:264178 (mixed mode))
SAP JCo build: 3.0.14
Exe directory: /tmp/sapinst_exe.8284.1532178621
```

If someone has face this kind of an issue earlier or can know the fix kindly help me with the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your virtual machine has the necessary requirements:

- 100GB of disk size
- 8GB of RAM

I increased my virtual machine RAM to 8192MB and I didn't receive this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may find many answers in the SAP ecosystem (blogs.sap.com, answers.sap.com) by googling "Unable to generate a new password for database login"

For example : https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/03/linux-for-newbies-installing-opensuse-on-oracle-virtualbox/comment-page-2/#comment-382956

Answer (score -2):

There is an issue with the install files: SAP ships the install files with an expired license for the SAP Sybase. You might want to check out this inexpensive Udemy course:
https://www.udemy.com/setup-free-sap-75-trial-system/learn/v4/overview
It helped me a lot. The course instructor provides a solution for the issue here:
https://www.udemy.com/setup-free-sap-75-trial-system/learn/v4/announcements?ids=1423610
Good luck!
---Hugo

PS. It AMAZES me that SAP doesn't have the decency to fix the install files and ship them with a CURRENT non-expired license key.

Comment: **"inexpensive" but the price I see is 10$ to 69$**

Comment: Yup, if SAP took Developer Relations seriously THEY would provide this type of material - free of charge.